# Boot in windows

Tags: windows-8, filesystems, filesystem-corruption

I have windows 8.1 installed on my laptop; I wanted to install ubuntu with a bootable usb. I think I unvolontary changed the type of the windows partition and now I can't boot on windows, i have the message " operating system not found", but I didn't format the partiton. there are maybe a software who can fix the partition system file ?

Comment: If you changed the partition type on the same partition windows was installed then it's gone.  You will have to reinstall Windows

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the type of a partition to a system partition without installing an operating system on it.The files of Windows now are just ordinary files such as a video or a picture in the HDD. You have to reinstall Windows.

Comment: I tried to make a factory reset to my laptop but it shows me the same error "operating system not found " and i already have windows 8 on it but i dont have the installation CD so how can i make the back factory or at least how can i install windows with my licence that i cant access anymore?thank you for your answers

Comment: if the recovery mode isn't working, you have to get the Windows copy specialized to your laptop brand, so the license key on the bottom of the laptop could work. You can contact the shop where you bought the laptop, they must have that copy of windows then they can use your already purchased license to activate it. You have to pay some money for them.